# Active Directory IS somehow allowing standard users full access to Active Directory Users and Computers

Tags: security, directory

I just got a new job a few weeks ago, and I noticed that somehow Active Directory is allowing standard users to modify users and groups in Active Directory Users and Computers.  Even though the standard users have not been delegated any control.

I created some test accounts in our Active Directory domain, and all of the test accounts have full access to Active Directory Users and Computers.  Providing that Remote Server Administration Tools is already installed on their client system.

I setup a new test domain in a virtual machine using Server 2012 R2.  Then I joined a test Windows 10 vm to the domain and the standard user was not able to make any changes to Active Directory.  The test user can open Active Directory Users and Computers; but they can't make any changes.

So there is something **majorly** wrong with our production Active Directory domain.  I just don't know where to look or how to resolve this issue.  I looked at our default domain policy and there wasn't anything there about giving users access to the domain.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with GPOs. It has to do with what access has been granted to principals (users or groups) against objects (in this case, other users at a minimum.)

Either your users are all Domain Admins, or delegation has happened (you say you've investigated that and ruled it out), or access has been granted via more specific means than delegation, which is really just some ease-of-use wrapped around ACLs. Find out where users are inheriting permissions against other users from, and remove it.

Comment: Where do I go to check where users are inheriting permissions from?

Comment: Open up ADUC, make sure you have the 'Advanced Features' enabled in the view menu. Then go look at the security tab for a user, group, or OU.  Look at who has what access.

Comment: Also look for unexpected group nestings. *e.g.* Domain Users in memberOf Domain Admins.

Comment: The domain users groups is not a member of the domain admin group.

The test user that I created is only a member of the domain user group.

The domain user group is users group.  The users group is not a member of any groups.  Since it's a build in group.

Comment: OK - so someone has granted permissions to "domain users" to be able to modify objects. Time to break out ADSI Edit, AD Explorer, or maybe just ADUC's security tab to track this down. Or just pay for a support call to Microsoft, that will probably be cheaper, depending on what your time is worth.